# C# iterate through the groupbox themselves

Tags: c#, groupbox

Iv been looking around and i havnt really found anything of meaning.

what i am trying to do, is change between groupboxes at the click of a button.

what i have is a windows form with 32 groupbox containers and there are 12 textboxes in each, some of the textboxes will receive a number the rest will remain empty; now where the following code works and i could copy and paste it 31 more times:

```
foreach (TextBox x in GROUPBOX1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            int A1 = 0;
            int.TryParse(x.Text, out A1);
            TOTAL += A1;   //defined outside of the method
        }
```

Where it checks all the textboxes in GROUPBOX1 and adds all the ones with values in together and ignores the empty textboxes.

what i would like to do, at the click of a button, is to increment `int GP =1` by `+1` and thus move to the next groupbox and its set of textboxes so that i can reuse the code in the `foreach` loop, to look something like this:

```
foreach (TextBox x in GROUPBOX+GP+.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            int A1 = 0;
            int.TryParse(x.Text, out A1);
            TOTAL += A1;   //defined outside of the method
        }
```

where `+GP+` would represent the `int GP =1` and its subsequent increments.

now i got the idea from:
`this.Controls["GROUPBOX"+box_number].Controls["LABEL"+label_prefix+"_"+label_number+"_LBL"].Text = valueToDisplayInLabel.ToString();`

which (with the appropriate assigned `int`) assigns values to certain labels in different groupboxes.
can this be done this way? all the groupboxes and textboxes have already been created.

what i am trying to accomplish is, the text boxes that receive a number will all be added together and that value will then be stored in a database as well as added to all the other "totals" and too stored in a database.

```
 foreach(GroupBox gb in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>())
    {
        foreach(TextBox tb in gb.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            int A1 = 0;
            int.TryParse(tb.Text, out A1);
            TOTAL += A1;   //defined outside of the method
        }
    }
```

this works great and all, but it doesnt allow me to get the totals of the combined text boxes per group box, like i want to store each groupbox total individually and add them together at a later stage, where as this takes ALL the textboxes that are in group boxes and dumps them in a list, iv added `List<int> TOTAL = new List<int>();` and `TOTAL.Insert(0, A1);` to try and make this work for me, but now its dumping all the textbox values into the list.

essentially im looking for `int GB1TOT, GB2TOT` etc etc then `int TOTAL = GB1TOT + GB2TOT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? Store the total per GroupBox into List GBtotal. Then you can get the total by summing them.

```
int Total;
List<int> GBTotal = new List<int>()
foreach(GroupBox gb in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>())
{
    int temp = 0;
    foreach(TextBox tb in gb.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        int A1 = 0;
        if(int.TryParse(tb.Text, out A1))
        {
           temp += A1;
        }
    }
    GBTotal.Add(temp);
}
Total = GBTotal.Sum();
```

You technically can use

```
Total = GBTotal[0] + GBTotal[1] + ....
```

Or use loop to get the total

Comment: this is a very clear explanation, has helped me quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Use two loops?

```
        foreach(GroupBox gb in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>())
        {
            foreach(TextBox tb in gb.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                int A1 = 0;
                int.TryParse(tb.Text, out A1);
                TOTAL += A1;   //defined outside of the method
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you, though this did point me in the right direction it didnt fully answer my question. +1